# Not Showing Any Results in List App Part When Using Text Filter Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, filter

I'm a site collection administrator in our SharePoint 2013 on premise instance. I want to use a text filter box to filter the contents of a list view app part based on a "Keywords" column. However, when I enter a known good keyword in the filter it always gives me "There are no items to show in this view of the "Video Links" list" message. I thought it might be because I was filtering on a field that wasn't visible in the current view, but when I tried connecting the filter to other fields that were in the view, I get the same results. I've tried changing the view and reconnecting the filter with no success. I've used the other filter web parts in other places in my site collection with no problem, but this is my first attempt using the text filter.

I'd appreciate any guidance to help me resolve this issue.